# Is there a way to bypass downloading of a jnlp file when using a web automation tool?

Tags: java, automation, jnlp

We're currently using a web automation tool that makes us download a localexecute.jnlp file everytime before running the testcase. Then it says downloading application and that continues for about 3-4 minutes.
Is there a way to bypass this, because it is very time consuming.
Thanks.

Comment: Web Start has a cache.  If it’s downloading a file every time, the server is probably providing the current date and time as a [Last-Modified header value](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-13.3.1) instead of the file’s modification time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just saving the JNLP file somewhere (e.g., right click on the link in the browser and save it) and then opening the saved file directly.

This assumes that the JNLP file doesn't change each time, which it may well do (for example, to add some secure token). In that case, it won't work.

You also have to keep in mind that since you are testing, you might be invalidating your tests by not loading the latest JNLP file each time.

Comment: Downloading the file isn't a problem, the problem is the downloading/running of the java application after that.
That takes a lot of time.

Comment: Check the Java control panel (Temporary files) and make sure you have the otpion set to store temporary files on your computer and that the cache is big enough to hold the application.